# Access hulu/youtube outside the USA

Tags: video, proxy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make my IP address appear to be from another country](https://superuser.com/questions/37687/make-my-ip-address-appear-to-be-from-another-country)

People outside of the USA have a rought time seeing hulu or some youtube videos. What proxies to do you use to see these kind of blocked sites?

**Moderator Note**: SuperUser.com does not endorse or defend any activity which may be used to circumvent local/state/national laws.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A little birdie once told me, I quote:

> Get a web host that gives you your own
>   Unix shell account such as Dreamhost
>   and create a SSH tunnel at your
>   terminal like so:
>
> ```
> ssh -D 1123 user@yourdomain.com
> ```
>
> What that achieves is that you'll be
>   directing everything through your
>   US-based hosting provider and appear
>   to have a US based IP address. It
>   works great when I'm not in the States
>   and still want to access the US iTunes
>   Store and Youtube. I guess Hulu will be fooled
>   too. :-)
>
> Dreamhost doesn't seem to get upset
>   when you redirect stuff through their
>   server, but I guess if you use too
>   much bandwidth, they'll get mad and send you an
>   angry letter. But it hasn't happened
>   yet...
>
> Now set localhost, port 1123 (or any
>   other port you specified earlier) as
>   your proxy in your network/browser
>   settings and you are good to go. This
>   is easier if you have a Unix-based OS
>   like OS X or Linux.
>
> Otherwise, for Windows, you'll need to configure SSH
>   tunneling using [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/).

**Disclaimer:** You probably be breaking the Digital Millennium Act. Everything that has been said is for educational purposes only. So be warned. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I am quite sure that is against the Hulu (or Youtube) ToS. I am assuming that you are inside USA but for some reasons these websites do not locate you properly ;)

If you have your own server within USA, you can always set up a SSH tunnel and use that as a 'proxy'. You have to have a fast internet connection (on both ends) for this to work because running everything through a tunnel will slow everything down. See guides on how to get it to work for [Windows with Putty](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/jp107/xp-remote/web-tunnel/) (guide is for Mozilla, although it isnt too hard to adapt it for newer browsers).

For Linux/Mac OS X systems, just run `ssh -D 9091 user@yourwebserver.com` in Terminal, remembering to replace `user` and `yourwebserver.com` with the correct details for your server. Then just set `localhost` as the proxy (SOCKS) server and `9091` as the port. If it does not allow you to specify a port, try `localhost:9091`.

Answer (score 3):

You can try through a VPN service.  [Here's a list](http://filesharefreak.com/2008/10/18/total-anonymity-a-list-of-vpn-service-providers/).

Answer (score 2):

Use [Tor](http://www.torproject.org/) and define your exit point as a location in the US.

Comment: Tor is way too slow for watching video in my experience.

Comment: +1 because I don't think this answer, while *wrong* deserves a neg 1.

Answer (score 1):

It used to be possible to use Hotspot Shield, however after a lot of people outside the USA trying it, they also blocked anomynous proxies.

[image]

Have patience and they will find a new way to enable it! However enabling it of course is not very legal!