# Access BBC video - proxy server? vpn?

Tags: vpn, proxy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make my IP address appear to be from another country](https://superuser.com/questions/37687/make-my-ip-address-appear-to-be-from-another-country)

I'd like to watch videos from the BBC web site.  This requires a UK ip address and I'm in the US.

What's the best way to do this?  I have no problem paying a reasonable amount.

EDIT:

After reading the answers to my original question, I'm looking for a reliable UK proxy server with enough bandwidth for video. I'm mainly seeking to watch BBC video (which requires a UK IP address), but may have other uses.

I have no problem paying a reasonable fee for a good proxy server.

Comment: I have merged your question "What’s a reliable UK proxy server with bandwidth for video?" with this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ToR and make the traffic route via UK server. [This post](http://hurwi.net/blog/?p=28) provides a detailed tutorial on how you can do so.

Comment: Are the UK servers reliable? Do they have adequate bandwidth?

Comment: foosion - 'm not sure, I haven't tried them.

Answer (score 1):

It's relatively easy to set up your browser to route your traffic through a proxy.  First, do a Google search for something like this: http://www.google.com/search?q=uk%20proxy%20list.  Then, change your browser to route through an IP address and port you find on a list like that.  In Firefox 3.5:

1. Preferences
2. Advanced
3. Network
4. Settings button under Connection
5. Select Manual proxy configuration
6. In the "HTTP Proxy" row, enter the IP address and port from that list

You may have to try a couple of IPs before finding one with suitable performance, and you may have to pick a proxy not marked as "transparent" to be able to fool the BBC site.  And make sure to switch back to "No proxy" before doing anything requiring security (i.e. checking your email or logging into your bank account).

Comment: What's a reliable UK proxy server with adequate bandwidth?

Comment: @foosion - I haven't tried any of the UK servers. Most lists provide a measurement of latency and percentage uptime, but I've not found those measurements to be very reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I used the one here, it is primarily a security program but has an unencrypted mode for efficient streaming of video. Plus a large network of UK proxy servers - [UK Proxy](http://www.anonymous-proxies.org/2009/02/using-iplayer-abroad-viewing-bbc-via.html)

Work really well for me, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this one before www.proxyplayer.co.uk - seems pretty good.
I tried free ones in the past and they were a bit hit and miss.
There are many about so I would suggest going with one that has a demo to make sure.
You can also use VPN, which I have also used in the past, but be aware that your entire computer's traffic will go through a VPN server whereas with a proxy server it's just your web traffic. You can always have 2 different browsers, one for the proxy server, one for your normal use to separate it :)