# Proxy to IP in US

Tags: networking, proxy, ip-address

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make my IP address appear to be from another country](https://superuser.com/questions/37687/make-my-ip-address-appear-to-be-from-another-country)

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make my IP address appear to be from another country](https://superuser.com/questions/37687/make-my-ip-address-appear-to-be-from-another-country)

Some online game in US restrict only IP in US. Is there any way to connect from outside US? Like using proxy? Can anyone suggest some proxy? Or keyword to search the proxy. I tried google 'us proxy' but the most top results seem to be advertisement. Hope the community can give me some suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: This is probably not allowed with your game anyways.

Answer (score 3):

Games, no matter which one that involves large quantities of data being sent will probably lag like crazy when going through a proxy...