# How can I hide, spoof or mask an IP address?

Tags: proxy, ip-address, spoofing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make my IP address appear to be from another country](https://superuser.com/questions/37687/make-my-ip-address-appear-to-be-from-another-country)

Several friends said they have done it with a proxy address. Is there a quick/easy way of doing it without having to purchase advertized software? I am able to get originating IP address with  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is impossible to spoof your ip address over the open internet over a TCP connection due to the [Three Way Handshake](http://www.inetdaemon.com/tutorials/internet/tcp/3-way_handshake.shtml).  PHP's $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] pulls the ip address directly from apaches tcp socket and there for cannot be influenced.  It is likely that you are looking for a proxy server.

Answer (score 1):

This probably belongs over on ServerFault but check out websites like:

[HideMyAss.com](http://www.hidemyass.com)

Just realize you are using a public proxy so don't send anything sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

[You can use TOR](http://www.torproject.org/)