# How to view a stream not available in my country

Tags: video, streaming, youtube

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make my IP address appear to be from another country](https://superuser.com/questions/37687/make-my-ip-address-appear-to-be-from-another-country)

Is there any way I can view a stream not available to my country? Via some proxy maybe? I think it's based on the IP address.

Comment: are you trying to view youtube

Comment: Yes. All you need a proxy service provider, if your network admin is not fobidding `ssh` etc.

Comment: I actually found it was a duplicatate from another question, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use Hide My Ass! http://www.hidemyass.com/
- Or try this http://www.zamzar.com/url/

Answer (score 0):

There are many subscription VPN services that you could use, but [FreeVPN](http://thefreevpn.com/) is free* (for some countries/servers).  I have used it to view BBC iPlayer when I am abroad, or view some American content that is usually unavailable to me while at home in the UK, like *The Daily Show* clips.

* Beware of the browser homepage hijacking.