# Getting a US IP address from outside the US

Tags: internet-connection, geolocation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make my IP address appear to be from another country](https://superuser.com/questions/37687/make-my-ip-address-appear-to-be-from-another-country)

I'm outside of the USA. How can I connect to the Internet using my country's Internet servers but be recognized as a USA user?

Answer (score 4):

You need a VPN/Proxy access in the US ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to knockout website based blocks you can use

https://www.sslunblock.com/ (well, timeout...)

or use the Firefox plugin "Modify Headers" to set your "X-Forwarded-For" header to an us ip adress.

- After installing open Tools -> Modify Headers in Firefox
- Klick on Add
- In the first field input: X-Forwarded-For, in the second an ip adress like 12.13.14.15
- Don't close the window and open your desired web adress

[image]

But this is only for websites, if you wan't other web services to work you need some us Proxy or VPN service.