# How can I make my IP address appear to be from another country to watch iPlayer?

Tags: windows-xp, ip-address

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make my IP address appear to be from another country](https://superuser.com/questions/37687/make-my-ip-address-appear-to-be-from-another-country)

I live in Bermuda – people seem to be able to use iPlayer, which is offered by the BBC (United Kingdom). Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

I am not really familiar with iPlayer but it is a very common thing. 
If you really want to make application you connect to see your IP as address from some other country - say "United Stated" then you should connect via an intermediary server that is located in US, which will redirect the traffic back and forth.

2 options there:

1. Proxy server, but they may not work as an application itself should
   support it.
2. VPN - Virtual Private Network - it will seemlessly make you appear as a part of some other network (say located in US) and it will apply encryption too.

Try google: [Search for "US vpn"](http://www.google.by/#q=us+vpn)

Read abou VPN: [VPN at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vpn)

Comment: iPlayer is from the BBC, it's UK-based.

Comment: yeah, but it matters not. most VPN providers will have a variety of choices of IP locations.

Comment: All a bit too techy for me guys- I know that the BBC etc in uk has to think that my computer is in the UK - There is something you can do or buy? that makes it think that. The I player is only available to peole in UK. You are talking to a non tech person, who is very appreciative of your hekp but it needs to in step by step info - or at least where can look up step by step... thanks all very much