# I want to watch BBC IPlayer and ITV Player in Bahrain

Tags: ip, tv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make my IP address appear to be from another country?](https://superuser.com/questions/37687/how-can-i-make-my-ip-address-appear-to-be-from-another-country)

How do I go about watching British TV programmes on British websites in Bahrain? They recognise that I am out of the UK and block me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a html proxy to mask your traffic as if it was from Britain.